# VBA Email Loop with Attachment and different recipient in CC does not execute

Tags: vba, excel, email

Dears,

I am posting this question since VBA code in another mails are not executing my purpose

Why cant I add .CC to my code and execute, it throws an error

```
Sub exporttoemail2()

 Dim OutlookApp As Object
 Dim MItem As Object
 Dim cell As Range
 Dim Subj As String
 Dim EmailAddr As String
 Dim Recipient As String
 Dim Msg As String
 Dim strLocation As String


 Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 With MItem
 .To = Range("D2") & ";" & Range("E2") & ";" & Range("F2")
 .Subject = "Hilti SOA - *Payment Notification* - " & Range("A2") & " - " & Range("B2")
 .htmlbody = "Body" 


 strLocation = Range("G2")

 .Attachments.Add (strLocation)

 .Display

 End With

End Sub
```

I caanot add .CC function to execute smoothly please help, Also could you help if I can loop the list in each row

Please refer snapshot of the excel file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY8St.jpg)

Comment: loop along with new attachment path in each row in column G

Answer (score 0):

.cc should be working for instance

```
.cc = "YourEmail@Email.com;"
```

What errors are you receiving?

Comment: TThe server thre an exception

Comment: only When I add .cc, it throws error, rest it works great

Comment: Can you help me loop for a data in 100 rows